# Webform as homepage

Tags: 7, webforms

Im using the webform module to create some reports.

I have only 2 pages available to users : submit a report and view existing reports.

Is there any way of making the "submit a report" page the default homepage ? ( right now it's a navigation item and i have the "add new content" link in the homepage)

I use a custom content-type for the form. Not sure if this is relevant or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can - just enter the path alias in `admin/config/system/site-information` or enter `node/[your webform node ID]` instead.

Comment: Thank you! ( waiting on the timer to allow me to mark this as the correct answer )

Comment: You're welcome - sometimes simple things aren't intuitive at first glance.